# Confused about how to get req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I cannot seem to get the body data shown on my server.  I am actually trying to get this in post/put/fetch calls, but to try to fix the problem, i've boiled it down to a simple .get, and it still won't appear.  Can anyone see why the body isn't showing on the server? I'm unable to get anything done in more complicated called due to this (like get the body of the req, but sticking to this simple example for now.)

This code is a fully working and sends data, just cant seem to access the body on the server.

*server.js*

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const Cat = require('./Cat');
const Dog = require('./Dog');

app.route('/animals')
  .get(function (req, res)  {
    console.log(req.body, 'req.body log'); //this returns {}
    res.send({ Cat, Dog });
  })

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

In react, if I call the following `callApi()` function, console.log shows the body data just fine on the front end, and the data can be used on the page.

*client call*

```
callApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('/animals');
  const body = await response.json();
  console.log(body) //shows all the data just fine!

  if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);

  return body;
};
```

Using node 9 and express 4.

Comment: res.body is the `body` property of the `response`, doesn't exist

Comment: I think you're looking for `req.body`, not `res.body`.

Comment: req.body will also be undefined for a get request anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX ah yes, true

Comment: Thanks, i also tried req.body but put res in the example (which ill switch in a second).  that returns an empty object.  

unfortunately, I made my question as simple as possible,  so I'm still stuck on my patch/put/post calls, but I appreciate these responses!

Comment: Since it’s not talking to database you are sending mock data. So obviously res.body will be undefined. You are sending dog and cat in response body and you doing console log of res.body before returning dog and cat as a res so it is undefined.

Comment: the data does exist, and you can make calls to it, I just tried to boil this example down for simplicity.

Thank you for all the replies!

Comment: First off, it would be `req.body`, not `res.body`.  And, there's only a `req.body` on a POST or PUT request, not on a GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing the request and response objects. But aside from that, I'll explain where/how to get data passed in from GET and POST/PUT requests.

When a GET request is made, you can pass data to the server via query params (i.e. /animals?type=cat). These parameters will be available already parsed in an object called `req.query`.

When a POST or PUT request is made, and you've applied the body parsing middleware (which you have done), the JSON will be available as a parsed object under `req.body`.

In your example, you have made a GET request, and have no provided any query string parameters. So `req.body` will return an empty object, as will `req.query`.

Your client call shows data because you've sent data back in the response via `res.send()`. This is totally unrelated to why `req.body` is an empty object in your case.

Try using `fetch('/animals?type=cat')` in your client call. Then, you will see that `req.query` returns `{ type: 'cat' }`.

Comment: Thank you! I was just about to ask for an example! I am definitely learning and fully appreciate your time.

That fetch call example is still not showing the data on the server, but it has helped me grasp the concept more.

Comment: That did it!!!!! I am not sure if i missed the query part of this, or if it was edited, but either way, you just helped me solve 3 days of frustration.  Thank you to you and other who have helped, you are a blessing!  I only wish I could upvote this more.